# How to read data like this from a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The text file is like

> 101    # an integer
>
> abcd   # a string
>
> 2      # a number that indicates how many 3-line structures will there be below
>
> 1.4   # some float number
>
> 2     # a number indicating how many numbers will there be in the next line
>
> 1 5   # 2 numbers
>
> 2.7   # another float number
>
> 3     # another number
>
> 4 2 7 # three numbers

and the output should be like
[101,'abcd',[1.4,[1,5]],[2.7,[4,2,7]]]

I can do it line by line, with readlines(), strip(), int(), and for loop, but I'm not sure how to do it like a pro.

P.S. there can be spaces and tabs and maybe empty lines randomly inserted in the text file. The input was originally intended for C program where it doesn't matter :(

My code:

```
    with open('data','r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    i=0
    while(i<len(lines)):
        course_id = int(lines[i])
        i+=1
        course_name = lines[i]
        i+=1 
        class_no = int(lines[i])
        i+=1
        for j in range(class_no):
            fav = float(lines[i])
            i+=2
            class_sched = lines[i].split(" ")
```

the variables read from the file will be handled afterwards

All those i+='s look absolutely hideous! And it seems to be a long Python program for this sort of task

Comment: Show us how you did it, and we'll help you "pro" it up.

Comment: Also, how will this algorithm know that the first line, `101`, doesn't indicate there isn't supposed to be a list of length `101` following that line?

Comment: @Brionius the first 2 lines are actually not so relevant. I attached my code above!

Comment: This belongs on Code Review, as it is explicitly code review.